# Safari takes space around the submit button

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I am trying to style buttons in my current cross browser project.

When I checked those buttons in Safari they looked different than in any other browser. In general, buttons looks the same in FF and Chrome. But in Safari buttons have sunknown extra space on top, bottom, left and right sides, so buttons looks wider in Safari rather than in Chrome or other browser. Can I remove the extra space on submit button in Safari?

My current css is:

```
.location-form-wrapper input[type="submit"] { 
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0; 
    float: left; 
    padding: 20px 23.8px; 
 } 
 input[type="submit"], input[type="button"], button, input[type="reset"] { 
    background: #facc26 none repeat scroll 0 0; 
    border: 1px solid transparent; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    box-shadow: none; 
    color: #ffffff; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    display: inline-block; 
    font-family: "latobold"; 
    font-size: 18px; 
    line-height: 1; 
    padding: 12px 26px; 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    transition: all 300ms linear 0s; 
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, provide your question with some code.

Comment: add some code will colorful your answer

Comment: .location-form-wrapper input[type="submit"] {
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px 23.8px;
}
input[type="submit"], input[type="button"], button, input[type="reset"] {
    background: #facc26 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "latobold";
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 12px 26px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: all 300ms linear 0s;
}

Comment: @Nishu you can **edit** your answer if you want to add something useful.

Comment: The code OP added in a comment is now in the question.

Answer (score 3):

I just came across this very issue, Safari 9.0.2. It might be too trivial, but I just added "margin: 0" to the button's CSS and the - well, margin - went away, letting the button fill the full area I intended for it.